# Updating Rails app from 5.0.7.2 to 6, is it necessary for a simple project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app for my portfolio. It is version 5.0.7.2
I'm at the point now where I want to implement bootstrap but I want to start getting comfortable using the new methods of Rails 6 using webpacker.

So, my question is, since it's just a portfolio app, would it be better just to implement bootstrap the old way or update it to 6 and use webpacker?

Or, since it wouldn't be that hard to just remake it in 6 and scaffold my features, should I just remake it?  The only issue with this is I don't want to lose my github repo since I have lots of kanban tasks in my projects section.

I am aware that you should update incrementally and tried updating to 5.2 but I had some issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Read StackOverflow's guidelines, this question is too opinionated, you won't find an answer here (actually, you'll find every kind of answer). SO is not the place to ask this kind of things.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip. So, stackoverflow as a whole is not the place, or this particular category, being "coding help" I believe it was. Or would the "other" category be more appropriate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask check this. Any possible answer for this question would be "it depends..." or "in my opinion" so it's a nono for SO as a whole (note the answer you selected does not actually solves your question, it's just an opinion and you could have received anthing else and at the end you'll have to chose what to do by yourself anyway). I'm not sure if there's any stack exchange site to ask things like this, it may be, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your courteous response.  I'm quite new here, if you can't already tell. I usually post on Reddit but was tired of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what your project for. If it's unimportant, and you wanna try new version, you can do that. Otherwise, i think we should only update for security reasons or performance reasons.